# Upload pine script to TradingView account via REST API

Tags: pine-script

I was wondering if there is an REST API for TradingView to upload Pine script? I'd like to be able to push my scripts from my source control platform in automated fashion (i.e. GitHub Actions).

Right now I can only upload the scripts manually via the TradingView Pine editor web app. And the version tracker is rudimentary and there's no change comparison with previous versions.

Thank you,
Anton

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Nope... Not yet. I don't think it's possible.